# Why is styles not getting applied to ToggleButton?

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:NotesViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

But the ToggleButton in toolbars size remains unchanged. If set the size right there with defintion, it changes but not through window styles in resources.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToolBar` applies its own `ToggleButton` style which you can override by defining a style with an `x:Key` of `ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey`:

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}"
       TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is nameless style so it automatically applies to all togglebuttons.

Comment: No. `ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey` get applied to all `ToggleButton` elements in a `ToolBar`. You must override this one as per my working example.

Comment: Thanks that does work! So essentially we have to set the style of Toolbar's togglebutton style. I am curious if we can do that directly as one style with the actual ToggleButton style declared inline just for understanding as an alternative way.

Comment: Just set the `x:Key` of your style to `{x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}`. Or define another style that is based on the implicit one as I did in my example.